# Spring controller variable not print in view page

Tags: spring

i am new to Spring Mvc,so i have this simple question below

**Code1:**

```
@RequestMapping("/hello")
    public ModelAndView hello()
    {
        String str="Be happy!!!!!";
        return new ModelAndView("hello","message",str);
    }
```

In hello.jsp View Page ,when i print str then i get result as  ${message}

**code2:**

```
@RequestMapping("/hello")
    public ModelAndView hello()
    {
        String str="Be happy!!!!!";
        return new ModelAndView("hellopage","message",str);
    }
```

but in hellopage.jsp i get result as Be happy!!!!!

so why above code1 does not print str string?

below is my view page jsp code and it is same for both hello.jsp and hellopage.jsp :

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">

</head>
<body>
${message}
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What error message does it throw ?

Comment: Please give a screen shot of your project structure

Comment: in hello.jsp View Page ,when i print str then i get result as ${message}  and in hellopage.jsp i get result as Be happy!!!!!

Comment: @PiraiSudie Check my answer and let us know !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `hello.jsp` put this expression `<%@ page isELIgnored="false"%>` at the top. Sometimes expression language automatically off for page

Comment: That's why I suggest you to use to expression !

Answer (score 1):

The EL expression doesn't get evaluated? That can have one or more of the following causes:

1. Application server in question doesn't support JSP 2.0.
2. The web.xml is not declared as Servlet 2.4 or higher.
3. The @page is configured with isELIgnored=true.
4. The web.xml is configured with true in .

In your case it looks like case no 3. Try to put isElIgnored=false in your jsp file.